# What algebraic condition corresponds to injectivity of a morphism of varieties?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, schemes

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec}$
Let $X = \Spec A$, $Y = \Spec B$ be affine complex varieties, that is reduced $\mathbb{C}$-schemes of finite type. Equivalently we can say that $A$ and $B$ are reduced finitely generated $\mathbb{C}$-algebras.

There should be a ring-theoretic condition on $\phi \in \operatorname{Hom}_\mathbb{C}(B, A) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_\mathsf{Sch}(X, Y)$ detecting whether the corresponding morphism of schemes is injective. Is there a nice way to phrase this condition? (besides the obvious thing saying that for every maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m} \subset B$ there is at most one maximal ideal $\mathfrak{n} \subset A$ such that $\phi^{-1}(\mathfrak{n}) = \mathfrak{m}$).

**My thoughts**: This condition has to be a generalization of both surjective morphisms and localizations and is stable under composition. But not every injective morphism of varieties is an immersion, e.g. the normalization of the cuspidal cubic $y^2 = x^3$.

Comment: Epimorphism in the category of rings?

Comment: I was actually unable to check that an epimorphism in the category of reduced commutative rings is also an epimorphism in the category of all commutative rings.

Comment: An epimorphism of rings corresponds to a monomorphism of affine schemes (in the category of affine schemes or, equivalently, of all schemes). Even for reduced affine schemes, this is a stronger condition than injectivity, as the normalization of the cusp demonstrates.

Comment: @YCor: If $K\to L$ is a field extension adjoining a p-th root to a characteristic p field, then this is epi in reduced rings but not in rings. (The kernel of $L\otimes_K L\to L$ is nilpotent.)

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly are you saying that the normalization of the cusp is not a monomorphism (in the category of reduced affine $\mathbb{C}$-schemes)? It seems like monomorphism and injectivity should be equivalent because morphisms of varieties are determined by their map on topological spaces (so injective => monomorphism) and monomorphism have to be injective (otherwise you have a contradiction by using two different maps from $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{C}$).

Comment: @CarlosEsparza Sorry, I was not quite clear: we have an injective morphism of reduced affine $\mathbb{C}$-schemes which is not a monomorphism of affine $\mathbb{C}$-schemes (but, as you say, it is a monomorphism in the category of reduced $\mathbb{C}$-schemes, affine or not).

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly And the way to see that it is not epi in the category of schemes is to consider $f, g: \mathbb{A}^1 \to \operatorname{Spec} k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2$ sending $t \mapsto \epsilon$ and $t \mapsto 0$.

Comment: @CarlosEsparza: Right (except it is "not mono"). Concerning epimorphisms of rings, you may have a look at [this seminar](http://www.numdam.org/volume/SAC_1967-1968__2/).

Comment: An answer is: for all $a \in A$ there is an $n > 0$ such that $(a \otimes 1 - 1 \otimes a)^n = 0$ in $A \otimes_B A$.